# Display {{pager}} to twig file

Tags: views, theming, paging

i am kinda new to drupal 8 so don't judge to hard...
 i have made template for drupal, that is in plain html,css and js...  than i imported it to drupal correctly as drupal documentation says whit his info.yml, libraries.yml and etc files at this moment everything is OK...
i have one page--front.html.twig file, that i have placed my main html mark-Up
with correct regions and so on. On other hand i have views-view.html.twig file that it has:

```
 set classes = [
    dom_id ? 'js-view-dom-id-' ~ dom_id, ]%}
<div{{ attributes.addClass(classes) }}>
  {{ title_prefix }}
  {{ title }}
  {{ title_suffix }}

  {% if header %}
    <header>
      {{ header }}
    </header>
  {% endif %}

  {{ exposed }}
  {{ attachment_before }}

  {{ rows }}
  {{ empty }}
  {{ pager }}

  {{ attachment_after }}
  {{ more }}

  {% if footer %}
    <footer>
      {{ footer }}
    </footer>
  {% endif %}

  {{ feed_icons }}
</div>
```

the code of ***{{ pager }}*** is in pager.html.twig and i contains this information:

```
{% if items %}
  <nav class="pager" role="navigation" aria-labelledby="pagination-heading">
    <h4 id="pagination-heading" class="visually-hidden">{{ 'Pagination'|t }}</h4>
    <ul class="pager__items js-pager__items">
      {# Print first item if we are not on the first page. #}
      {% if items.first %}
        <li class="pager__item pager__item--first">
          <a href="{{ items.first.href }}" title="{{ 'Go to first page'|t }}"{{ items.first.attributes|without('href', 'title') }}>
            <span class="visually-hidden">{{ 'First page'|t }}</span>
            <span aria-hidden="true">{{ items.first.text|default('« First'|t) }}</span>
          </a>
        </li>
      {% endif %}
      {# Print previous item if we are not on the first page. #}
      {% if items.previous %}
        <li class="pager__item pager__item--previous">
          <a href="{{ items.previous.href }}" title="{{ 'Go to previous page'|t }}" rel="prev"{{ items.previous.attributes|without('href', 'title', 'rel') }}>
            <span class="visually-hidden">{{ 'Previous page'|t }}</span>
            <span aria-hidden="true">{{ items.previous.text|default('‹ Previous'|t) }}</span>
          </a>
        </li>
      {% endif %}
      {# Add an ellipsis if there are further previous pages. #}
      {% if ellipses.previous %}
        <li class="pager__item pager__item--ellipsis" role="presentation">&hellip;</li>
      {% endif %}
      {# Now generate the actual pager piece. #}
      {% for key, item in items.pages %}
        <li class="pager__item{{ current == key ? ' is-active' : '' }}">
          {% if current == key %}
            {% set title = 'Current page'|t %}
          {% else %}
            {% set title = 'Go to page @key'|t({'@key': key}) %}
          {% endif %}
          <a href="{{ item.href }}" title="{{ title }}"{{ item.attributes|without('href', 'title') }}>
            <span class="visually-hidden">
              {{ current == key ? 'Current page'|t : 'Page'|t }}
            </span>
            {{- key -}}
          </a>
        </li>
      {% endfor %}
      {# Add an ellipsis if there are further next pages. #}
      {% if ellipses.next %}
        <li class="pager__item pager__item--ellipsis" role="presentation">&hellip;</li>
      {% endif %}
      {# Print next item if we are not on the last page. #}
      {% if items.next %}
        <li class="pager__item pager__item--next">
          <a href="{{ items.next.href }}" title="{{ 'Go to next page'|t }}" rel="next"{{ items.next.attributes|without('href', 'title', 'rel') }}>
            <span class="visually-hidden">{{ 'Next page'|t }}</span>
            <span aria-hidden="true">{{ items.next.text|default('Next ›'|t) }}</span>
          </a>
        </li>
      {% endif %}
      {# Print last item if we are not on the last page. #}
      {% if items.last %}
        <li class="pager__item pager__item--last">
          <a href="{{ items.last.href }}" title="{{ 'Go to last page'|t }}"{{ items.last.attributes|without('href', 'title') }}>
            <span class="visually-hidden">{{ 'Last page'|t }}</span>
            <span aria-hidden="true">{{ items.last.text|default('Last »'|t) }}</span>
          </a>
        </li>
      {% endif %}
    </ul>
  </nav>
{% endif %}
```

here is mu question... when i put the ***{{ pager }}***  to my page--front.html.twig than nothing happens... why? why dose views-view.html.twig can execute the  ***{{ pager }}***  and it can't views-view.html.twig? what am I doing wrong?
 thanks in advance

p.s: I forgot to say that in the front page i have activated the pager... and it shows correctly but i want it to be on aver location than it is right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take a look in `/core/themes/stable/templates/views`

In **views-view.html.twig** at the top, there is a commented out part that says:

- **Available variables:**
- attributes: Remaining HTML attributes for the element.
- css_name: A css-safe version of the view name.
- css_class: The user-specified classes names, if any.
- header: The optional header.
- footer: The optional footer.
- rows: The results of the view query, if any.
- empty: The content to display if there are no rows.
- **pager: The optional pager next/prev links to display.**
- exposed: Exposed widget form/info to display.
- feed_icons: Optional feed icons to display.
- more: An optional link to the next page of results.
- title: Title of the view, only used when displaying in the admin preview.
- title_prefix: Additional output populated by modules, intended to be
- displayed in front of the view title.
- title_suffix: Additional output populated by modules, intended to be
- displayed after the view title.
- attachment_before: An optional attachment view to be displayed before the
- view content.
- attachment_after: An optional attachment view to be displayed after the
- view content.
- dom_id: Unique id for every view being printed to give unique class for
- Javascript.
  *
- @see template_preprocess_views_view()

> As you can see **pager** is listed under Available variables

---

While in `/core/themes/bartik/templates`

**page.html.twig**

- **Available variables:**
- General utility variables:
- base_path: The base URL path of the Drupal installation. Will usually be
- "/" unless you have installed Drupal in a sub-directory.
- is_front: A flag indicating if the current page is the front page.
- logged_in: A flag indicating if the user is registered and signed in.
- is_admin: A flag indicating if the user has permission to access
- administration pages.
  *
- Site identity:
- front_page: The URL of the front page. Use this instead of base_path when
- linking to the front page. This includes the language domain or prefix.
  *
- Page content (in order of occurrence in the default page.html.twig):
- node: Fully loaded node, if there is an automatically-loaded node
- associated with the page and the node ID is the second argument in the
- page's path (e.g. node/12345 and node/12345/revisions, but not
- comment/reply/12345).
  *
- Regions:
- page.header: Items for the header region.
- page.pre_content: Items for the pre-content region.
- page.breadcrumb: Items for the breadcrumb region.
- page.highlighted: Items for the highlighted region.
- page.help: Dynamic help text, mostly for admin pages.
- page.content: The main content of the current page.
  *
- @see template_preprocess_page()
- @see html.html.twig

> As you can see **pager is NOT** listed under Available variables

---

The correct solution is that you need to modify/create the **views-view--frontpage.html.twig** and not the page--front.html.twig

So go to `core/modules/views/templates` and copy views-view.html.twig and rename it to views-view--frontpage.html.twig and make changes that you need. The views-view--frontpage.html.twig needs to go in `/theme/yourtheme/templates` folder.

Comment: thanks a lot for replying so fast... the information that you prove is very useful.... but i am interested of using specific code in specific region, so can i use {{ pager }} to any html.twig files (if yes, than how?) or this is impossible?

Comment: @GeorgeChanturia as I mention in my answer, since `{{ pager }}` is not listed under Available variables in page.html.twig, you cannot use `{{ pager }}` here. Furthermore, the pager belongs to the frontpage view and not the front page. So front page wouldn't know what `{{ pager }}` is.

Comment: @GeorgeChanturia `so can i use {{ pager }} to any html.twig files (if yes, than how?)` Yes it is possible, you would have to create a custom twig variable using a preprocess function which will render the pager programmatically.

Comment: thank you so mach and sorry for damu questions... I will try what you say and will reply... thanks...

Comment: @NoSssweat please give us a pointer as to how one can render a pager in a preprocess function